# Streaming audio + still image using ffmpeg

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, azure-media-services

I'm streaming an audio source to azure media services using RTMP and a raspberry pi. This works great using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://...
```

But know we want to add an image to this flv container because azure media player wants a video component.

So I added video using this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -g 50 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://...
```

Yet it crashes with following log:

```
ffmpeg version N-86429-gf8593c2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
configuration: --prefix=/home/pi/ffmpeg/dependencies/output --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/home/pi/ffmpeg/dependencies/output/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/pi/ffmpeg/dependencies/output/lib --extra-libs='-lx264 -lpthread -lm -ldl'
libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
libavcodec     57. 98.100 / 57. 98.100
libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
libavfilter     6. 91.100 /  6. 91.100
libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'image.png':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 600x400 [SAR 5669:5669 DAR 3:2], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, alsa, from 'hw:1,0':
Duration: N/A, start: 1497522851.947685, bitrate: 768 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> flv1 (flv))
Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[alsa @ 0x18e3330] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: :sunglasses:
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://aptus2-aptus.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/b962f6df8d3b4e97a608981d019faaa4/default':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(progressive), 600x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.98.100 flv
    Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.98.100 aac
frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=      56kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=5700.0kbits/sframe=   12 fps= 12 q=2.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=1227.2kbits/sframe=   21 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=      72kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate= 739.8kbits/sframe=   29 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=      79kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate= 573.9kbits/s[alsa @ 0x18e3330] ALSA buffer xrun.
frame=   39 fps= 15 q=2.0 size=      85kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate= 246.9kbits/sframe=   50 fps= 16 q=2.0 size=      86kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate= 251.4kbits/sframe=   60 fps= 17 q=2.0 size=     157kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate= 457.1kbits/sframe=   71 fps= 17 q=2.0 size=     159kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate= 462.2kbits/s[alsa @ 0x18e3330] ALSA buffer xrun.
frame=   81 fps= 18 q=2.0 size=     161kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate= 289.0kbits/sframe=   92 fps= 18 q=2.0 size=     163kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate= 291.8kbits/sframe=  103 fps= 18 q=2.0 size=     234kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate= 418.5kbits/sframe=  114 fps= 19 q=2.0 size=     235kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate= 421.3kbits/s[alsa @ 0x18e3330] ALSA buffer xrun.
frame=  124 fps= 19 q=2.0 size=     238kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 292.8kbits/sframe=  135 fps= 19 q=2.0 size=     240kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 294.7kbits/sframe=  146 fps= 19 q=2.0 size=     241kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 296.6kbits/sav_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
[flv @ 0x18f9ea0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x18f9ea0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://aptus2-aptus.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/b962f6df8d3b4e97a608981d019faaa4/default: Broken pipe
frame=  151 fps= 15 q=1.6 Lsize=     306kB time=00:00:06.70 bitrate= 373.5kbits/s speed=0.644x    
video:284kB audio:24kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 0x18fe6e0] Qavg: 3428.370
Conversion failed!
```

what am I doing wrong? Any help would be awesome!